# Showing $\mathbb{R}[X]/(X^2+1) \cong \mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $f:\mathbb{R}[X] \to \mathbb{C}, f \mapsto f(i)$. How can I show $\ker(f) = (X^2+1)$? It is obvious that the element $X^2+1$ belongs to the kernel, but how can I see that its ideal is all of the kernel?

Comment: This is false. Consider $X^6 + 1 \in \ker f$, and many more (among those, all complex polynomials of the form $(X-i)P(X)$)

Comment: @AlexR note $x^6+1=(x^2+1)(x^4-x^2+1)$

Comment: Okay by $(A)$ you mean the minimal ideal containig $A$. Sorry for the misinterpretation. Are you alloed to use the fact
$$P \in \mathbb{R}[X], P(z) = 0 \Leftrightarrow P(\bar{z}) = 0$$
? Then you would be done for $(X-i)(X+i) = (X^2+1)$ would have to be a factor of any element of the kernel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: Polynomial division. If $f(x)$ is any polynomial, then there exist unique polynomials $q(x)$ and $r(x)$ such that
$$
f(x)=q(x)(x^2+1)+r(x)
$$
and $\deg r(x)<2$. Show that $f(i)=r(i)$ and go from there.

Comment: All the polynomials above have real coefficients.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a way to do it that uses a bit more theory.

$\mathbb{R}[X]$ is a PID, and you already know that $(X^2 + 1)$ is contained in the kernel of the given homomorphism.

But since $X^2 + 1$ is irreducible and the ring is a PID, this means that $(X^2+1)$ is a maximal ideal, so it must in fact be the entire kernel (since clearly the map is not identically $0$).

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is a polynomial such that $f(a)=0$, then $f$ is divisible by $(x-a)$. If $f$ is real, then for $a\in\mathbb C:f(\overline{a})=\overline{f(a)}$.

Thus, if $f(i)=0$, then $f(-i)=0$ and $f$ is divisible by both $(x+i)$ and $(x-i)$.